# Set Excel spreadsheet worksheet title

Tags: asp-classic, export-to-excel

Working with Classic Asp file which generates an Excel .xls file.  I am wondering if there is a way to set the worksheet title, as currently is just uses the file name, so if the filename is Ad_Results.xls then the worksheet will be Ad_Results 1?

This is the code that I am using to create the file initially:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Shoom_Ad_Results.xls" 
Response.CharSet = "iso-8859-1"
```

I've looked on google but there is no definitive version, nor is it stated if in fact it can be done.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Classic ASP but I *just* did this in ASP.NET. Maybe you can find it useful.

```
Response.Write("<html xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">");
Response.Write("<head>");
Response.Write("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;charset=windows-1252\">");
Response.Write("<!--[if gte mso 9]>");
Response.Write("<xml>");
Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorkbook>");
Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheets>");
Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheet>");
Response.Write("<x:Name>Sheet1</x:Name>");
Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheet>");
Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheets>");
Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorkbook>");
Response.Write("</xml>");
Response.Write("<![endif]-->");
Response.Write("</head>");
```

Comment: Converted it to classic asp and it worked like a charm.